# jupyter_contrib_nbextensions missing after jQuery UI endpoints change (HTTP 404 error in NotebookApp logs)

Tags: python, jquery, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, http-status-code-404

I've auto-upgraded Jupyter Notebook to the latest version released on PyPi:

```
pip install notebook==6.5.1
```

In this version however, [Jupyter Notebook Extensions](https://jupyter-contrib-nbextensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) have disappeared, and both their endpoint and their configurator menu item are missing from the Notebook API and web interface.

Looking into application logs we find the likely reason: HTTP 404 errors indicating that jQuery UI endpoints have been moved and Jupyter client has not kept up with this change:

```
[W 19:32:16.567 NotebookApp] 404 GET /static/components/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css (*.47.102.*) 1.040000ms referer=https://*.mirekphd.*:*/nbextensions/
[W 19:32:17.439 NotebookApp] 404 GET /static/components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js?v=20221027192637 (*.47.102.*) 0.830000ms referer=https://*.mirekphd.*:*/nbextensions/
```

Downgrading `notebook` seems to be the temporary workaround:

```
pip install notebook==6.4.12
```

Please keep us posted when a solution is in place and we can unpin the package.